# %ms in C programming language

Tags: c

I wrote some code on C using `%ms` in `scanf`.

```
    char *note;
    scanf(" %m[^\n]s", &note);

    printf(note);

    struct contact contact;

    strcpy(contact.name, name);
    strcpy(contact.note, *note);
    strcpy(contact.number, num);
```

contact structure:

```
struct contact
{
    char name[50];
    char number[11];
    char *note;
};
```

I can print the value `note` above but I can't use it `strcpy` or I don't know how to pass it to a function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `struct contract`, specifcally `contact.note`? Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Likely it should be `strcpy(contact.note,note)`

Comment: Your title is misleading -- you actually used the `%m[…]` format, followed by an unnecessary `s`.  You should know that (a) the `m` modifier is a nonstandard (GNU) extension, and (b) you might need to explicitly `free` the malloc'ed pointer later.  But `note` should be a fine string pointer, and you should be able to copy it with `strcpy` — but you don't need the `*` when you do.

Comment: Actually, though, I would *not* recommend using `strcpy` here.  The whole point of the `m` modifier is that you don't need to worry how long the string is.  But if you do something like `strcpy(contact.note, note)`, you have to worry about how much memory `contact.note` points to.  So I recommend doing `contact.note = note`.

Comment: Actually, @SteveSummit, `m` is a POSIX extension to [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) compared with Standard C.  I believe it was first implemented in the GNU library.  It is not yet implemented everywhere (macOS 10.x and 11.x does not support it, for example).

Comment: It is crucial to check the return value from `scanf()` when using the `m` modifier.  If any conversion fails, then the strings allocated via the `m` modifier are _all_ set to NULL.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is it!  Thanks for the tip.  (Just missed the 5 minute window to update my comment, though.)

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you very much! contact.note = note worked! You made my day seriously, I was trying to find a solution for 2 hours!!!